# Merging numpy ndarray from CSVs

Tags: python, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I have the following code:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
nysedatafile = os.getcwd() + '/nyse.txt';
nysedata = genfromtxt(nysedatafile, delimiter='\t', names=True, dtype=None);
nasdaqdatafile = os.getcwd() + '/nasdaq.txt';
nasdaqdata = genfromtxt(nasdaqdatafile, delimiter='\t', names=True, dtype=None);
```

Now I would like to merge the data from the 2 CSVs and I tried various functions:

For example:

```
import numpy as np;
alldata = np.array(np.concatenate((nysedata, nasdaqdata)));
print('NYSE stocks:' + str(nysedata.shape[0]));
print('NASDAQ stocks:' + str(nasdaqdata.shape[0]));
print('ALL stocks:' + str(alldata.shape[0]));
```

returns:

```
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

I tried as well `numpy.vstack` and to try to call an array on it.
I expect the last print to give the sum of the rows of the two previous csv files.

---

EDIT:
This command:

```
print('NYSE shape:' + str(nysedata.shape));
print('NASDAQ shape:' + str(nasdaqdata.shape));
print('NYSE dtype:' + str(nysedata.dtype));
print('NASDAQ dtype:' + str(nasdaqdata.dtype));
```

returns:

```
NYSE shape:(3257,)
NASDAQ shape:(2719,)
NYSE dtype:[('Symbol', 'S14'), ('Name', 'S62'), ('LastSale', 'S9'), ('MarketCap', '<f8'), ('ADR_TSO', 'S3'), ('IPOyear', 'S4'), ('Sector', 'S21'), ('industry', 'S62'), ('Summary_Quote', 'S38')]
NASDAQ dtype:[('Symbol', 'S14'), ('Name', 'S62'), ('LastSale', 'S7'), ('MarketCap', '<f8'), ('ADR_TSO', 'S3'), ('IPOyear', 'S4'), ('Sector', 'S21'), ('industry', 'S62'), ('Summary_Quote', 'S34')]
```

Comment: Post the `shape` and `dtype` of the two arrays.

Comment: @unutbu : done, Mr Ubuntu anagram :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `np.vstack` (or `np.concatenate`) is raising an error is because the dtypes of the two arrays do not match.

Notice the very last field: `('Summary_Quote', 'S38')` versus `('Summary_Quote', 'S34')`. nysedata's `Summary_Quote` column is 38 bytes long, while `nasdaqdata`'s column is only 34 bytes long.
(Edit: The `LastSale` column suffers a similar problem.)

This happened because `genfromtxt` guesses the dtype of the columns when the `dtype = None` parameter is set. For string columns, `genfromtxt` determines the minimum number of bytes needed to contain
all the strings in that column.

So to stack the two arrays, the smaller one has to be promoted to the larger one's dtype:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as recfunctions
recfunctions.stack_arrays([nysedata,nasdaqdata.astype(nysedata.dtype)], usemask = False)
```

(My previous answer used np.vstack. This results in a 2-dimensional array of shape (N,1). `recfunctions.stack_arrays` returns a 1-dimensional array of shape (N,). Since `nysedata` and `nasdaqdata` are 1-dimensional, I think it is better to return a 1-dimensional array too.)

Possibly an easier solution would be to concatenate the two csv files first and then call `genfromtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()    
nysedatafile = os.path.join(cwd, 'nyse.txt')
nasdaqdatafile = os.path.join(cwd, 'nasdaq.txt')
alldatafile = os.path.join(cwd, 'all.txt')
with open(nysedatafile) as f1, open(nasdaqdatafile) as f2, open(alldatafile, 'w') as g:
    for line in f1:
        g.write(line)
    next(f2)
    for line in f2:
        g.write(line)

alldata = np.genfromtxt(alldatafile, delimiter='\t', names=True, dtype=None)
```

Comment: Thank you, I validated my files as following: nysedata = genfromtxt(nysedatafile, delimiter='\t', names=True, dtype=[('Symbol', 'S14'), ('Name', 'S62'), ('LastSale', 'S9'), ('MarketCap', '<f8'), ('ADR_TSO', 'S3'), ('IPOyear', 'S4'), ('Sector', 'S21'), ('industry', 'S62'), ('Summary_Quote', 'S38')]);

Comment: On another note (I am new to Python), what is the standard method to read the files line by line ? (in order to concatenate them I need to skip the headers of all but the first file)

Comment: @BlueTrin: I've edited the post to show one way to concatenate the files while skipping the first line of the second file.

Comment: thanks, it is my first Python program :) I learned many things in your reply and comment.